# How to detect Back Key in my CustomView

Tags: android, key, detect, back

I want to detect Back Key event in my CustomView (e.g., EditText). In many case, it has been achieved by overriding the `onKeyDown()` or `dispatchKeyEvent()`, under the condition that my CustomView obtains focus.

**CustomView.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        ..... 
        return true;
    }else{
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

However, if an Activity including the CustomView is also overriding the `onKeyDown()` or `dispatchKeyEvent()`, it couldn't work much. That is, the Activity has obtained the Back-KeyEvent before the CustomView has.

I preferentially want to catch the Back-KeyEvent before Activity does.

please tell me some ideas about this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement this to capture the BACK button before it is dispatched to the IME:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyPreIme(int,android.view.KeyEvent)

Answer (score 0):

Override onKeyDown in your Activity and **return false**. So that the event gets propagated to other views as well.

> If you handled the event, return true. If you want to allow the event
>   to be handled by the next receiver, return false.

Comment: It is not quite true. Method `onKeyDown` in `Activity` is called when a key was pressed down and not handled by any of the views inside of the activity.` First is called onKeyDown on focused View, then on Activity, then on the rest.

Comment: But as far as we are returning false, it will go to the next receiver. Right? Though answer by @MoshErsan may be preferable to do this. But as mentioned in the question, onKeyDown is already overridden in Activity, so you have to return false there, no matter what! :)

Comment: It's just as you say. By your favor, I could understand about the order in which methods are called. Actually when I tried, it was `View#onKeyPreIme`,`Activity#dispatchKeyEvent`, `View#dispatchKeyEvent `, `View#onKeyDown`, then lastly, `Activity#onKeyDown`. Thanks!

Comment: @Gottie Exactly! It is also worth checking what happens if you have more than one View (f.e. two EditTexts), and one of them has focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
setFocusable(true)
requestFocus()
```

on your customview